# AmE had done/were to do it

Tags: conditional-constructions

Which one would be correct:

> 1. If they **were to do** it, he would not agree.
> 2. If they **had done** it, he would not agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean different things.

'If they were to do it...' means that they might (or might not) do it in the future, and if they do, he will not agree.

'If they had done it...' means that they definitely have not (in the past) done it, but if they had, he would not (in the present) agree. '... he would not have agreed', putting his disagreement in the past with their action, might be a bit more typical, but I think either is possible.

In order to use the first form in the past tense, you'd use 'if they were to have done it...' which would still imply that they might not have.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the correct way to say it is **If they were to do it, he would not agree**. The alternative is **If they had done it, he would not agree** but **agree** is in present tense with its surroundings and so that sentence would probably be more suitable as **If they had done it, he would not have agreed**.